# Consume asmx webservice in pcl

Tags: c#, web-services, asmx, portable-class-library

I am developing an app which uses third party `.asmx` web service. And I am using PCL(Portable class Libraries) in my app.

So I wanted to consume those `.asmx` web services in my app. Problem is PCL doesn't support traditional web service viz `.asmx`. It supports `WCF` web services.

I have read many articles, they suggests me that from `wsdl` write `WCF` web service. But since all web services are third party, I need to write proxy in client app (Where web service is being called) such that it will convert `WCF` call to `.asmx`.

Also I have tried this example using PCL. 
I am using [this](http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx) asmx web service

```
public class PerformLogIn : ILogInService
    {
         public string LogIn(string code)
         {
             ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient obj = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient();
             obj.GetCityForecastByZIPAsync(code);
             ServiceReference1.WeatherReturn get = new ServiceReference1.WeatherReturn();

             return (get.Temperature);
         }
```

But I am not getting any result.
So do anybody have idea how to do that??

Comment: You don't have to do any conversion. Just use "Add Service Reference" like you normally would.

Comment: @JohnSaunders: Thnx for reply.. I did that... It is giving me `asych` methods. Whose return type is `void`. So how to get response of service??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eureka I found it..

Use following code snippet

```
public class PerformLogIn : ILogInService
    {
         public void LogIn(string code)
         {
             ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient obj = new ServiceReference1.WeatherSoapClient(
                                        new BasicHttpBinding(),
                                        new EndpointAddress("http://wsf.cdyne.com/WeatherWS/Weather.asmx"));

             obj.GetCityForecastByZIPAsync(code);
             obj.GetCityForecastByZIPCompleted+=getResult;
         }
         void getResult(Object sender,GetCityForecastByZIPCompletedEventArgs e)
         {
             string error = null;

             if (e.Error != null)
                 error = e.Error.Message;
             else if (e.Cancelled)
                 error = "cancelled";
             var result = e.Result; 
         }
   }
```

So your response from web service is being stored in `result` variable. Just fetch the data whatever needed and return it to calling client.

Comment: Hi Rohit. I am trying to implement something similar to this but am having a problem. In between the void function call and the completed event triggering there is a null exception error. You can see more details here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38708785/using-asmx-in-portable-library. Any advice?